# Python find and replace within a text file

Tags: regex, python-2.7, replace

Hello I am having trouble getting my Python to work correctly. I have a text file of the following format:

```
3|1|15382|25364||
3|2|15384|25364||
43|1|27444|27297|4849569|
43|2|27486|27297|4329265|
107|2|24940|684269||
115|1|24869|684269||
```

My current Python code:

```
f1 = open('myFile.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('myFileOutput.txt', 'w')
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line.replace('|\n', ','))
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

My current code will create a myFileOutput.txt that looks like this:

> 3|1|15382|25364|,3|2|15384|25364|,43|1|27444|27297|4849569,43|2|27486|27297|4329265,107|2|24940|684269|,115|1|24869|684269||

What I want is when there is no data between two || it should keep the second |. My current code doesn't do that.  Here is an example of what I want it to look like:

> 3|1|15382|25364||,3|2|15384|25364||,43|1|27444|27297|4849569,43|2|27486|27297|4329265,107|2|24940|684269||,115|1|24869|684269||

I am using Python 2.7.3 and also these files can get up to 500MB in size.

Comment: `f2.write(line.replace('|\n', ',').replace('|,', '||,'))`

Comment: @Ωmega that seems to work. can you explain how that second .replace works? if not its okay, thanks!

Comment: @michael The second part in Ωmega's solution just assumes that the only commas in the file are the ones you just added. So if you have a '|,', it must mean that you used to have a '||'. So to get what you wanted, it turns it into a '||,'.

Comment: @michael - Read Daivd's comment. As you have no commas in original input, the second replace just fix what first made wrong :)

Comment: is there any way to edit my f2.write() so that ONLY the LAST line will strip the '|\n' and replace it with nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `f2.write(line.replace('|\n', ',').replace('|,', '||,'))`

Answer (score -1):

One easy way to do this would be to first replace "||\n" with "|||\n", so the new code would be

```
f1 = open('myFile.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('myFileOutput.txt', 'w')
for line in f1:
    line = line.replace('||\n', '|||\n')
    f2.write(line.replace('|\n', ','))
f1.close()
f2.close()
```